# Getting UIView from TiUIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, titanium

I am working on a custom module for iOS in Titanium. In that module I need to get an `UIView` object. For example, user is creating a view with method `Ti.UI.createView` in javascript, then I need solution to get that view as `UIView` in my module objective-C code.

javascript:

```
MyModule.getView({ view: sampleView });
```

objective-c:

```
-(void)getView:(id)args{
    //some objective-C code to get UIView from args
}
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: If you've done it, you can answer this question and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer, that works for me

javascript:

```
MyModule.getView( view );
```

objective-c:

```
-(void)getView:(id)args {
   TiUIViewProxy* viewProxy = (TiUIViewProxy*)[args objectAtIndex:0];
   UIView *view = (UIView*)[viewProxy view];
}
```

The `view` will actually be a TiUIView class object, which inherits from UIView.